# Matching a string which occurs after a certain pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to match a string which occurs after a certain pattern but I am not able to come up with a regex to do that (I am using Java).

For example, let's say I have this string,

```
caa,abb,ksmf,fsksf,fkfs,admkf
```

and I want my regex to match only those commas which are prefixed by `abb`. How do I do that? Is it even possible using regexes?

If I use the regex `abb,` it matches the whole string `abb,` but I only want to match the comma after that.

I ask this because I wanted to use this regex in a split method which accepts a regex. If I pass `abb,` as the regex, it will consider the string `abb,` to be the delimiter and not the `,` which I want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you could just match "abb," (might need to escape the ,), then add "abb" back to any string prior to that match.

Comment: @billjamesdev, this would work, but that would only be a good workaround to the problem ... what if I only wanted to use regexes?

Comment: Use: `(?<=abb),`

Comment: @anubhava, that works! thanks a lot :) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        String test = "caa,abb,ksmf,fsksf,fkfs,admkf";
        String regex = "(?<=abb),";
        String[] split = test.split(regex);
        for(String s : split){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

Output:
caa,abb
ksmf,fsksf,fkfs,admkf

See here for information:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html